# django search returns all entries upon double click

Tags: django, search

I created search tool within my website using some help from internet.
Problem is when I double click on seach button it brings all entries available, but work if you type whatever you search for. Code in views.py is below.

```
class SearchResultsView(ListView):
    model = Entry
    template_name = 'wpb/search.html'


    def get_queryset(self): # новый
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        object_list = Entry.objects.filter(
            Q(title__contains=query.upper()) | Q(link__icontains=query)
        )
        return object_list
```

Code for search.html is below:

```
<ul>
  {% for entry in object_list %}
    <li>
      <a href="{{ entry.link }}">{{ entry.title }}</a>

    </li>
  {% empty %}
      <h4>Ничего не найдено.</h4>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Cuoldn't find anything similar in the internet.

Comment: you can check you `query` before returning queryset, and if it is empty show user a error message

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I set the object_list to empty if no query.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `__icontains` filter, which will return all of the entries if you don't write anything in the form. This is because you're sending something like this to your database:

```
SELECT ... WHERE headline ILIKE '%%';
```

This will query everything. To fix this, you can use some JavaScript to disable the search when the user doesn't write anything in the input.